# Why request response 404 or 400 is None?

Tags: python, request

I try this code,
because I didn't send json,so the request in 400 BAD_REQUEST
But I'm confused about the result

```
import requests
a= None
try:
    a = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data/")
except :
    print "exception"

if a :
    print "a is not none"
    print a.status_code
    print a.request 
else:
    print "a is none"
    print a.status_code
    print a.content
    print a.request
```

it print :

```
a is none
400
{"Fail":"Format not valid}"}
<PreparedRequest [POST]>
```

if a is none,why I can print `a.status_code,print a.content,print a.request`??

Comment: Maybe check with `if a is not None`..

Comment: `a` is not `None`, it is probably an object whose boolean value is evaluated to `False`. You can double check that by seeing what `bool(a)` returns.